# Adding 2 Images with Android Renderscript

Tags: android, android-bitmap, renderscript

I am trying to increase exposure time of my camera by adding the values of 2 back to back capture. It took far too long to calculate with Java so I decided to attempt Renderscript. I seem to have all of the bugs worked out but the end result has some pretty weird effects[image: Images get blue and green discoloration]

Most of the chair and floor in this image are fine but areas get mostly bright green and blue discolouration.

Here is the Renderscript file:

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(edu.marquette.mcw.smartme)

rs_allocation extra_alloc;

uchar4 __attribute__((kernel)) combine(uchar4 a, uint32_t x, uint32_t y)
{
    // get second image
    uchar4 b = rsGetElementAt_uchar4(extra_alloc, x, y);

    // combine red value
    uint32_t red = a.r + b.r;
    //set to max value if it exceeds it
    if(255 - a.r < b.r)
    {
        red = 255;
    }
    a.r = red;

    // combine green value
    uint32_t green = a.g + b.g;
    if(255 - a.g < b.g)
    {
        green = 255;
    }
    a.g = green;

    // combine blue value
    uint32_t blue = a.b + b.b;
    if(255 - a.b < b.b)
    {
        blue = 255;
    }
    a.b = blue;

    // return result
    return a;
}
```

And here is the Java code that executes the Renderscript:

```
// Load Script
RenderScript RS = RenderScript.create(callingFrag.getActivity());
ScriptC_combine script = new ScriptC_combine(RS);

output = Bitmap.createBitmap(combined.getWidth(), combined.getHeight(), combined.getConfig());

// Send in bitmaps
Allocation aAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(RS, combined);
Allocation bAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(RS, exposures.remove(0));
Allocation outputAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(RS, output);
script.set_extra_alloc(bAllocation);

// Run Script
script.forEach_combine(aAllocation, outputAllocation);
App.log("Combine Time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
outputAllocation.copyTo(output);
```

I couldn't find anything in the logs that appeared to be a warning/error. Any ideas of how this can be solved?

Comment: Assuming that both images are in RGB space, it may help to watch: https://youtu.be/LKnqECcg6Gw

Comment: Have you tried working on the colors using rsUnpackColor8888(a) ?
It returns a float4 with the colors between 0 and 1
and in the end you just have to return rsPackColorTo8888(f4.r, f4.g, f4.b, f4.a);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found a library that covers exactly what I need and more in only about 1 line.

[easyRS](https://github.com/silvaren/easyrs) allows me to combined 2 images with just:

```
Blend.add(rs, inputBitmap, inputBitmap2);
```